# Kerberos with SPNEGO not working inside docker container

Tags: docker, kerberos, spnego

I am trying to implement SSO using kerberos. I was successfully able to do it on the host machine.

Once I copied the same files in the docker container it stopped working.

The error I am getting is like below.

```
Key for the principal HTTP/HOSTNAME@DOMAIN not available in default key tab

org.springframework.ldap.AuthenticationException: Unable to obtain password from user
; nested exception is javax.naming.AuthenticationException: Unable to obtain password from user
 [Root exception is javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user
]
        at org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException(LdapUtils.java:191)
        at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.createContext(AbstractContextSource.java:355)
        at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.doGetContext(AbstractContextSource.java:139)
        at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.getReadOnlyContext(AbstractContextSource.java:158)
        at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.executeReadOnly(LdapTemplate.java:802)
        at org.springframework.security.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.searchForSingleEntry(SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.java:316)
        at org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch.searchForUser(FilterBasedLdapUserSearch.java:127)
        at org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(LdapUserDetailsService.java:56)
        at org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(KerberosServiceAut
```

Comment: What have you actually tried?  Where's your code?

Comment: I have created a web application where user should be able to access this portal if the user has a valid kerberos ticket. I was able to achieve this.   The service is able to intercept the user requests with valid kerberos ticket and allowing the user to access the portal. But when i deployed the same application inside the docker container its throwing the error what i have put above.

Comment: Got it fixed. Problem was the container had a file /etc/krb5.keytab which was getting picked. Once i explicitly set the path of keytab file it started working.